# FFmpeg darkening video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, codec

I'm trying to switch my encoding setup from Mac to Windows. As part of that, I'm trying to get FFmpeg working as my ProRes encoder.

I'm converting from 10-bit uncompressed to ProRes 422 HQ. When I do, colors are noticeably darker, by comparison to the original uncompressed, and a ProRes from Adobe Media Encoder.

I'm using

`./ffmpeg -i testfile.mov -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -c:a copy prores422_ks4.mov`

I've tried the ProRes and Prores_KS codec, with the same result.
I ran MediaInfo on the files an got the following:

Adobe Media Encoder (correct color)

> ```
> Format                                   : MPEG-4
> Format profile                           : QuickTime
> Codec ID                                 : qt   2005.03 (qt  )
> File size                                : 208 MiB
> Duration                                 : 13 s 13 ms
> Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
> Overall bit rate                         : 134 Mb/s
> Encoded date                             : UTC 2018-03-14 22:08:26
> Tagged date                              : UTC 2018-03-14 22:09:38
> Writing library                          : Apple QuickTime
> TIM                                      : 00:59:53:00
> TSC                                      : 24000
> TSZ                                      : 1001
>
> Video
> ID                                       : 1
> Format                                   : ProRes
> Format version                           : Version 0
> Format profile                           : 422 HQ
> Codec ID                                 : apch
> Duration                                 : 13 s 13 ms
> Bit rate mode                            : Variable
> Bit rate                                 : 132 Mb/s
> Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
> Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
> Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
> Frame rate mode                          : Constant
> Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
> Color space                              : YUV
> Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
> Scan type                                : Progressive
> Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 2.654
> Stream size                              : 205 MiB (98%)
> Writing library                          : Apple
> Language                                 : English
> Encoded date                             : UTC 2018-03-14 22:08:26
> Tagged date                              : UTC 2018-03-14 22:08:26
> Color primaries                          : BT.709
> Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
> Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
> ```

FFmpeg (darker colors)

> ```
> Format                                   : MPEG-4
> Format profile                           : QuickTime
> Codec ID                                 : qt   0000.02 (qt  )
> File size                                : 195 MiB
> Duration                                 : 13 s 55 ms
> Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
> Overall bit rate                         : 125 Mb/s
> Writing application                      : Lavf57.83.100
>
> Video
> ID                                       : 1
> Format                                   : ProRes
> Format version                           : Version 0
> Format profile                           : 422 HQ
> Codec ID                                 : apch
> Duration                                 : 13 s 55 ms
> Bit rate mode                            : Variable
> Bit rate                                 : 124 Mb/s
> Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
> Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
> Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
> Frame rate mode                          : Constant
> Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
> Color space                              : YUV
> Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
> Scan type                                : Progressive
> Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 2.485
> Stream size                              : 192 MiB (99%)
> Writing library                          : Lavc
> Language                                 : English
> Color primaries                          : BT.709
> Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
> Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
> ```

Original Footage

> ```
> Format                                   : MPEG-4
> Format profile                           : QuickTime
> Codec ID                                 : qt   2005.03 (qt  )
> File size                                : 2.42 GiB
> Duration                                 : 13 s 55 ms
> Overall bit rate                         : 1 592 Mb/s
> Encoded date                             : UTC 2018-03-14 20:32:39
> Tagged date                              : UTC 2018-03-14 20:32:39
>
> Video
> ID                                       : 1
> Format                                   : RGB
> Codec ID                                 : r210
> Codec ID/Hint                            : Blackmagic Design
> Duration                                 : 13 s 55 ms
> Bit rate mode                            : Constant
> Bit rate                                 : 1 591 Mb/s
> Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
> Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
> Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
> Frame rate mode                          : Constant
> Frame rate                               : 23.976 (24000/1001) FPS
> Color space                              : YUV
> Scan type                                : Progressive
> Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 32.000
> Stream size                              : 2.42 GiB (100%)
> Language                                 : English
> Encoded date                             : UTC 2018-03-14 20:32:39
> Tagged date                              : UTC 2018-03-14 20:32:39
> Color primaries                          : BT.709
> Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
> Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
> ```

Here is the output from FFMpeg

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.2 : stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'testfile.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2018-03-14T20:32:39.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:13.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1592473 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: r210 (r210 / 0x30313272), rgb48le(10 bpc, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 1590933 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 24k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-14T20:32:39.000000Z
      handler_name    : Linux Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : 10 bit packed RGB (r210)
      timecode        : 00:59:53:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 0
      creation_time   : 2018-03-14T20:32:39.000000Z
      handler_name    : Libquicktime Time Code Media Handler
      reel_name       : untitled
      timecode        : 00:59:53:00
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-14T20:32:39.000000Z
      handler_name    : Linux Alias Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (r210 (native) -> prores (prores_ks))
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mov, to 'prores422_ks9.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (prores_ks) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 24k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-14T20:32:39.000000Z
      handler_name    : Linux Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:59:53:00
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 prores_ks
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16be (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-14T20:32:39.000000Z
      handler_name    : Linux Alias Data Handler
```

Here are some example images of what the change looks like. I can't post full frames or anything identifying of the content, but here are some color swatches.

[Media Encoder Beige](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c3GF.png)

[FFMpeg Beige](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVqIi.png)

[Media Encoder Blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da85Y.png)

[FFMpeg Blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPW7A.png)

[Correct Color Bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNOaU.png)

[FFMpeg Color Bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pV3E.jpg)

Note: I trimmed a black frame or two off the end in Media Encoder

I'm a noob at FFmpeg, so any help would be greatly appreciated! I assume I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: is it only getting darker or is it getting "less contrasty" all together? could well be that FFmpeg is interpreting your source material as 0-255, when it actually already is 16-240 (I know it's 10bit, but you get the idea...). also, the ffmpeg banner would help - and knowing something about the source.

Comment: @flolilolilo I just updated the post with pictures, MediaInfo of the uncompressed source and FFmpeg readout. Thank you so much!

Comment: Uh...can you deliver something more..contrasty? ideally, it would be some [color-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:EBU_Colorbars.svg), so we can see if it affects the whole spectrum of levels (vulgo: everything gets darker) or if it just compresses the top and bottom parts of the spectrum.

Comment: still, from what I see, I would bet it comes down to the conversion from RGB48 (as ffmpeg calls it) to YUV422. I will check if I can find anything on that topic...

Comment: @flolilolilo I just added some color bars. Thanks so much for the help. I'll keep searching too!

Comment: as you can see, it only darkens the lighter colors - black even gets lighter. therefore, my guess that it tries to make your video TV-safe (16-235 instead of 0-255 - that's 8 bit, I know ;-) ). I have to go to sleep now, but perhaps [this ffmpeg trac "Impossible to transcode full range RGB videos"](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3409) might be of use. Will look into more of it tomorrow ;-).

Comment: @flolilolilo Now that I know what to search for, I see it is a common issue. I looked into that post and could'nt find a solution, but I'll keep searching :D Thank you!

Comment: Was a solution to this problem ever found?